# AngularJs show negative or positive number

Tags: angularjs

I need to show positive or negative number. The problem is that I get data from an api where I have a delta -X for positive and X for negative.

So to show my data I need to multiply per -1.

I have this code:

```
{{myData * -1}}
```

But I need a way to add a + symbol to my data in case it is positive. If I have (-120*-1) I should get +120.

How could I add plus to my number?

Comment: All you need to do is create a function on the scope and then call it in the expression.

Comment: Just as a note, Josh's answer is win (and a good reason to upgrade) because it keeps html in control of how the data is displayed. I don't really want my controller to have to add a plus sign to my output.

Comment: I agree. As a side note, the ternary operator works also on 1.1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The AngularJS way to do this is via a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). Filters are used for formatting and displaying data. Moreover they can be easily reused in multiple places. There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931831/using-attribute-text-value-in-angularjs-directive/19948312#19948312) with an example of a how a custom filter can be used to address a formatting problem.

Comment: Here's what the filter would look like to meet OP's requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/Asheq/z9yv1x2j/

Answer (score 16):

Adding a '+' symbol to your output could be as simple as this:

```
{{number > 0 ? '+' : ''}}{{number}}
```

If you need to do it all over the place, I would probably write a directive to append the symbol.

**Note:** *The ternary operator will only work in Angular 1.2+*

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/NNgw6/

Comment: I should specify that I'm on angular 1.0.6

Comment: Great answer for 1.2+

Comment: @m59 - Yeah, I was pretty stoked when they added that.

Comment: I have a ngif check where negative is getting displayed like -2, i want it to be just 2 without negative sign,,,Tried the ternary way {{Details < 0 ? '':'-'}}{{Details}} bt nt wrkng

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your need here, you should be able to use a function to get the data rather than access the integer directly.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var foo = 1;
  $scope.getData = function() {
    if (foo > 0) {
       foo = '+'+parseInt(foo);
    }
    return foo;
  }
});

<p>{{getData()}}</p> <!-- displays "+1" -->
```

[Live demo here. (click)](http://jsbin.com/OXaKAFEv/4/edit)

Comment: I need to show "+" to my data. For example: if I have -12 I should output +12. If I try Math.abs(-12), I get simply 12 without "+"

Comment: @Tropicalista Ok, I see what you mean now. Check out my updated answer and demo. Should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "filter" way:

```
app.filter('plusOrMinus', function(){
    return function(input){
        input = input ? input : 0
        return input > 0 ? "+"+input : input
    }
})
```

then on your view:

```
<p>{{number | plusOrMinus}}</p>
```